# Roll off rate vs filter order?

Tags: filters, butterworth

The concept of "increasing roll off rate with increasing filter order" applies only to butter worth or also chebyshev and other filter types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming it's a low-pass filter and assuming that the filter order equals the number of poles and there are no zeros in the s-domain transfer function, then the rolloff at the edge of the passband through the stopband is -20 dB/decade (or -6 dB/octave) multiplied by the order of the filter.

now Butterworth and Tchebychev Type 1 filters have no zeros.

Tchebychev Type 2 and Elliptical filters have zeros, so the ultimate rolloff is not there, the gain remains at the stopband level.

Comment: Tchebychev ?? same as chebyshev?

Comment: yes, i think that i got the spelling of it most originally.  hence why the polynomial functions are shown as $$ T_n(x) $$ but [there are others who think differently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pafnuty_Chebyshev#Transliteration).